# Symbol not found in flat namespace '_exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister' in Odoo16 Mac m1

Tags: python, odoo-16

After installing Odoo from source and requirements I run

```
python3 odoo-bin --addons-path addons -r odoo -w odoo  and get
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nasko/odoo_mac/odoo/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister'
```

How can I solve this?

I have tried to reinstall `psql` but nothing happen.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the library manually. You can find a description [here](https://lxml.de/build.html#building-lxml-on-macos-x).

I have executed these steps:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/lxml/lxml/releases/download/lxml-4.9.3/lxml-4.9.3.tar.gz 
tar xzf lxml-4.9.3.tar.gz
cd lxml-4.9.3
python3.9 setup.py build --static-deps
STATIC_DEPS=true python3.9 setup.py install --static-deps
```

Comment: thanks. i was unable to use tiktoken with Jupyter, thanks to your solution it worked.