# cl100k_base (openAI) encoding does not compile with python program

Tags: encoding, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am running a program that uses the gpt 3.5 turbo 16k model, which uses the cl100k_base encoding. When I run this in an IDE, it works perfectly however when I compile the program, it can't identify cl100k_base encoding.Is there a way around this?

To compile the program with cl100k_base encoding. I expected the encoding to be bundled in when compiled but it appears it hasnt - it works perfectly in the IDE

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `pyinstaller`, add this line to your install command.

```
--hidden-import=tiktoken_ext.openai_public --hidden-import=tiktoken_ext
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on M1 chip with Jupyter. Implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76776773/15741905) solved it for me.

Basically:

```
curl -LO https://github.com/lxml/lxml/releases/download/lxml-4.9.4/lxml-4.9.4.tar.gz 
tar xzf lxml-4.9.4.tar.gz
cd lxml-4.9.4
python3 setup.py build --static-deps
pip install lxml-4.9.4/
```